# Unable to access html content from xml

Tags: php, xml, parsing, object, xml-parsing

I am Converting a XML string into a SimpleXMLElement object and accessing keys and elements of that object. in this process i am facing one issue that anchor tags in the xml are not accessable by object.

```
$resultobject = simplexml_load_string($xml,null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

**$resultobject** display as :

```
[channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
     [item] => Array
      (
       [0] => 
         SimpleXMLElement Object
          (
           [title] => "Crises and deadlocks when they occur" - www.google.com
          )
      )
    )
```

But when trying to access **title**

```
echo $resultobject->channel->item[0]->title;
```

**Getting Result:**

**"Crises and deadlocks when they occur" -**

Link **www.google.com** or whatever link was there was missing in every entry. what is problem here?

Comment: Can you post your `XML` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo htmlentities($resultobject->channel->item[0]->title);
```